# SQL: joining table of person, trainings and absolved trainings in one statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Good evening,

I bet a similar question has been posted before and I just couldn't find it. I am currently struggling with the following scenario: 
I need to join a table containing employees with another table containing internal trainings bookable by the employees and ideally using another table containing the training records of already taken trainings for each person and training.

Sample structure:

```
table "person"
  -> person_id
  -> last_name
  -> first_name

table "training"
  -> training_id
  -> training_name

table "person2training"
  -> person_ref
  -> training_ref
```

Sample data:

```
person: 
  -> person_id: 1, last_name: Muller, first_name: Peter
  -> person_id: 2, last_name: Schmitz, first_name: Horst

training:
  -> training_id: 1, training_name: "Sorting books"
  -> training_id: 2, training_name: "Licking stamps"

person2training:
  -> person_ref: 2, training_ref: 2
```

Desired result (vertically joined):

```
person_id  | training_1    | training_2
-----------|---------------|----------
1          | NULL          | NULL
2          | NULL          | 1 (or true)
```

Tables are stored in an Oracle 11g database, right now I create the data shown in "Desired Result" using array_merge() in PHP but I feel that a pure SQL solution would perform better with growing numbers of employees and trainings.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any real way that these are linked together?

Comment: Of course. I guess record for HR department or training center would show this. It needs some pivotting work or select from xml i guess.

Comment: @vasin1987 you are totally right, it's for a training center. The idea is to create a matrix of all possible combinations of trainees and trainings with the relevant participation state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming that the OP was trying to find if all users had training 1 and 2.**

I do not think you need all 3 tables for the info you need. Try this

```
SELECT 
    p.person_id,
    (SELECT 1 FROM person2training pt 
        WHERE p.person_id = pt.person_id AND pt.training_id = 1) [training_1],
    (SELECT 1 FROM person2training pt 
        WHERE p.person_id = pt.person_id AND pt.training_id = 2) [training_2]
FROM person p
```

You can also use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to get the same result.

```
 SELECT 
    p.person_id,
    CASE WHEN pt1.person_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END [training_1],
    CASE WHEN pt2.person_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END [training_2]
FROM person p
    LEFT JOIN person2training pt1 ON p.person_id = pt1.person_id AND pt1.training_id = 1
    LEFT JOIN person2training pt2 ON p.person_id = pt2.person_id AND pt2.training_id = 2
```

**EDIT**: A query using PIVOT, when the trainings are not known before hand.
Used `LEFT OUTER JOIN` because there could be people without any training.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT p.person_id, pt.training_ref
      FROM person p
          LEFT OUTER JOIN person_training pt ON p.person_id = pt.person_ref)
PIVOT (COUNT(training_ref) AS trained FOR (training_ref) IN (SELECT training_id 
                                                            FROM training))
```

Comment: You forgot that the training table can contain an unlimited number of trainings so static SQL won't do.

Comment: @SaschaM78 Then your solution has to be `PIVOT` once you have done the join. Even in that case you should know the trainings that exist beforehand, `unlimited` may not work.

Comment: I think using PIVOT will be part of my solution and adding the participation record data using PHP may be the way to go. Thanks for pointing me to the PIVOT clause, I never heard of it yet and it may be really useful!

Comment: @SaschaM78 My last edit should get you a solution with each persons training.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, it keeps on telling me "00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"". Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @SaschaM78 Modified the Column Name, and this should fix the error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44742/discussion-between-sascham78-and-user2989408)